New Outlook WIndows App drag and drop emails and attachments to webapplications
From the 'old' Outlook Windows App drag and drop emails and attachments to webapplications was possible by using Outlook Add-ins (See here). And with the newest Edge or Chrome browser it seems to be possible even without this add-ins.
But with the new Outlook Windows App (olk.exe) that seems not to be possible again. Dragging emails and attachments to the Explorer is working. But it isn't nice to first download the items and than upload them. We want it directly.
Any ideas?
